# Correct SPF record to avoid softfail for emails sent from domain address using Gmail?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, mail-forwarding

I have a domain address, such as `me@example.com`, which forwards to Gmail.
Gmail is configured to 'send email as' `me@example.com`, using example.com's SMTP server.

Emails sent from Gmail as `me@example.com` to another Gmail address deliver fine.
Replies to that email back to `me@example.com`, are going into spam.

Every one of those replies comes in with the following message in the header:

`spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning somebodyelse@gmail.com does not designate IP_ADDRESS_OF_EXAMPLE.COM_MX as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=somebodyelse@gmail.com;`

I have adjusted the spf DNS record for `example.com` to contain:
`v=spf1 mx include:netblocks.dreamhost.com include:relay.mailchannels.net include:_spf.google.com -all`

(The first two are what Dreamhost, my domain host, default to. I added google.com).

I had thought that adjustment would fix it, but I'm clearly missing something. What is it?

UPDATE -- full header pasted below. I've replaced email addresses with PERSON1 (the Gmail account configured to send as me@example.com), PERSON99 (the gmail account being sent to and replied from), and me@example.com as above:

```
Delivered-To: PERSON1@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a0c:ffce:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h14csp219058qvv;
        Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:38 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJwBCKVNM176Kci8wKH2Ok8kvwMvoTHZwIyDHC85JoNXx0qqfleGv7BkrehLNC7//RVelwcc
X-Received: by 2002:a17:90b:3716:: with SMTP id mg22mr2579388pjb.157.1616579858373;
        Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:38 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1616579858; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=nWxwOQwSSO4CG4muH1Ts9tHF8Wi30YpaPHFLXux8ysocZePKwzCp6DlLdo/h3RlTnT
         oFcVykFbuMLWzJyqNBdlHeXUJwnl5vg0TRnSDH1dM9Hn9q4VwVgkh01kTtciYfHpi8TM
         D12M2rkfCRNSpJB5tBuLz8FIyXcz4453vjsxrBhq0bJgSdrMInO+GsCCYyCzkAq8agHL
         0ZdM6LhoM5Y5NvuxCeoPZSFRZdkXlhVubiU7/Ou/G5o0+ktEo0e3otwwPCcuufEGpUzw
         3CNMiock7VlySx85tyAVlKE1exk49R55Me1+XILaemeiMiiaiidoTcCQ1ypjfhlVDp1S
         TC8w==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=to:subject:message-id:date:from:in-reply-to:references:mime-version
         :dkim-signature;
        bh=IxbTYU9ihz312Yq0VFwswippxC7wgB0q/P4K8ivRjh8=;
        b=jzf3qfhCi4ggMh/m0ZAoYVmMfIHYZdfEvGxQrG5K70VJ5mch9smO01kp5zg0hnmQ2R
         vZdS6pGtD7V4R62+k12SDJ8teZboqjqCtUQpFczUZhbI9rpFcgqtCs3cn72odaGPAN6P
         L10ydmf9DABbEwqCm4B+15S8/0fZMwyuPWDEQcTB/nNj/ff0yuQ87zdviBw9fhFI2NCY
         mC+7+x2DlZJt8t2hZmAGLyZne0RKVQ4WWKCCIeIhyz0oXri+bu8DRC1Z/fIGNx9DVtM2
         BtLkDo8x01PrsBK54rpsoCx2ktXFU4hl67cgylfcvLKQDs/U7FBMziJOsfXCylHz1nai
         yWSA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=hNgluIwd;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning PERSON99@gmail.com does not designate 64.90.62.163 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=PERSON99@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Return-Path: <PERSON99@gmail.com>
Received: from pdx1-sub0-mail-mx18.g.dreamhost.com (mx1.dreamhost.com. [64.90.62.163])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e25si1847211pgl.414.2021.03.24.02.57.38
        for <PERSON1@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:38 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning PERSON99@gmail.com does not designate 64.90.62.163 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.90.62.163;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com header.s=20161025 header.b=hNgluIwd;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning PERSON99@gmail.com does not designate 64.90.62.163 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=PERSON99@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from mail-wm1-f53.google.com (mail-wm1-f53.google.com [209.85.128.53]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by pdx1-sub0-mail-mx18.g.dreamhost.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id AD929AEB7B for <me@example.com>; Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by mail-wm1-f53.google.com with SMTP id k128so10133768wmk.4
        for <me@example.com>; Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:37 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=IxbTYU9ihz312Yq0VFwswippxC7wgB0q/P4K8ivRjh8=;
        b=hNgluIwd0E0Zx/hvBSVbpKFr7VAZKIUpzTMqnDJ/rSeQOj1vWblPddfOYC1lVrh6ZB
         NGp4pw4gUQV4JUDSU5WKdyDYrE+cOzZgs4/63uNYxQljwLbwsxDq+BDUTKvpCFuYU/hy
         MHZsOCga8Rv8guxACVHKJZOgWni4xxnNxfdxNqOeIlhQQ1Tf7ZhzdkOusUd6Cr3BVl+4
         Ix2FiJ31KOYoy/6ElxswiVV1v+EWBFT+aVQO3Mifup1dBa2mQLLtlQmvFQG/QUlQMMcJ
         KzMfCQT8ao4zAf4sn9YREwLpwTLXpo/uHnF55xCfTAl398BrQ5gKnHTfWVF51vjWN9RQ
         0ltA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date
         :message-id:subject:to;
        bh=IxbTYU9ihz312Yq0VFwswippxC7wgB0q/P4K8ivRjh8=;
        b=I8NCHhqijKrpmBqE3/thZBtfSiyi67s1+GeTf2kQI62JQZbpT5MzSzGfsdwgDSNgvD
         TXA3nKuqv7dnpU35ZplnyDMghp/pUWcTsSE1znKZ7sX9jG6vTlIImHBvvNs6g9gzA3lV
         LgjLssA+pma0QuGQPZDsEDPx7+nxNL1EG7VDk6XCCicXet806EQxtq5UO2wiVp1ORnex
         iJpD63JDWjckDJ7LMM4bRso/oqNjArmKDBiAK22Ma/Z2zRVqf9Dv+hpkvMad7rFVdOQZ
         Mo6JNCe0l5L590VI7//8QU/I748rJodTcloe1Kt8p8TDFIX62OKMVnZj698ZCi15tsOf
         46Aw==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOAM530PRD38wY7l2GyuJJQJtnxvGBsjBGkAA3f0pHmo+mxqF52LHB2k 1+4iAH3cKmuoc72Q+/1ejOzbq5uxTxTOyLO/SSi8suUK
X-Received: by 2002:a05:600c:4f55:: with SMTP id m21mr2062135wmq.11.1616579855739; Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:35 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
References: <CABnao97UwPfxpSTZvZYahxzFRn2aBQTmha1J4PP0LH2cHeb4Xg@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <CABnao97UwPfxpSTZvZYahxzFRn2aBQTmha1J4PP0LH2cHeb4Xg@mail.gmail.com>
From: Julie Turner <PERSON99@gmail.com>
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 04:57:24 -0500
Message-ID: <CAG7xKKru_OgpYSBgy5DxJ992jG=ddBqZkLo_F2DdpeQ+7-K-zg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: testing
To: ME <me@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="0000000000000d6fc105be45545e"
```

Comment: Can you provide the full headers please?

Comment: I added the full headers of the reply that comes back with the SPF softfail..

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with PERSON99 email settings. The mail from `PERSON99@gmail.com` is sent from dreamhost as shown in this header.

```
Return-Path: <PERSON99@gmail.com>
Received: from pdx1-sub0-mail-mx18.g.dreamhost.com (mx1.dreamhost.com. [64.90.62.163])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e25si1847211pgl.414.2021.03.24.02.57.38
        for <PERSON1@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:57:38 -0700 (PDT)
```

Only google may choose who is sending mail with addresses from @gmail.com -- that's the whole SPF point --  and 64.90.62.163 is not in google's list.

Comment: Right. So I mail out from Gmail as me@there.com to PERSON99. The SPF for there.com includes google.com as authorized, so that email is happily received. PERSON99 then replies, which necessarily sends it through there.com (because that's where it came from) ... and Google is unhappy because it doesn't authorize there.com's mail servers. Is there any way around this?

Comment: It looks like perhaps Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS) may be the way around this. Unfortunately my domain host doesn't support it.

Comment: «is there a way around it ?» No. not at all. But PERSON99's Mail User Agent should be configured to use google servers to submit new mail when the mail sent are from @gmail.com. That what is done when you configure a gmail account with thunderbird, or apple Mail or outlook (can't quit say for this last one I've never used it) See for example https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail .

Comment: You can't use SRS to send new mails. SRS is a way for your server to forward an arriving mail ; not to send new mails. If the from address is @gmail.com, it has to come from a gmail server. Otherwise, spammers and other nasty people would immediately use the trick to fake mails.